# Monogame layers drawing over each other - why?

Tags: c#, monogame, tiled

I'm new to Monogame and C#. I'm attempting to render a test Tiled map on the screen using [TiledSharp](https://github.com/marshallward/TiledSharp). However, when I try to draw multiple layers, they're clearly looping and drawing over one another.

Here's my draw method code:

```
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);



        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin(sortMode: SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, blendState: BlendState.AlphaBlend, samplerState: SamplerState.PointClamp, null, null, null,
            Matrix.CreateScale(6.0f)); 

        for (currentTileLayer=0; currentTileLayer < easyMap.TileLayers.Count; currentTileLayer++)


        {
            Console.WriteLine(easyMap.TileLayers[currentTileLayer].Name.ToString());


            for (var i = 0; i < easyMap.TileLayers[currentTileLayer].Tiles.Count; i++)
            {

                int gid = easyMap.TileLayers[currentTileLayer].Tiles[i].Gid;

                // empty tile, do nothing
                // gid => global id of tile
                if (gid == 0)
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    int tileFrame = gid - 1;
                    int column = tileFrame % tilesetTilesWide;
                    int row = (int)Math.Floor((double)tileFrame / (double)tilesetTilesWide);

                    float x = (i % easyMap.Width) * easyMap.TileWidth;
                    float y = (float)Math.Floor(i / (double)easyMap.Width) * easyMap.TileHeight;

                    Rectangle tileSetRec = new Rectangle(tileWidth * column, tileHeight * row, tileWidth, tileHeight);

                    spriteBatch.Draw(easyTileset, new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, tileWidth, tileHeight), tileSetRec, Color.White);



                }



            }


        }


            spriteBatch.End();

        base.Draw(gameTime);

    }
```

My original map looks like this:

[image]

When I run the code it looks like this:

[image]

There are three layers to the map. How can I fix my loops? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use sorted layers since Tiled supports them very well. Using layers gives you much more possibilies in terms of map design. I also enables to make you character hide behind objects and so on. 
In tiled, create your background layer first if needed several layers on top to avoid a wrong drawing order.

A simple solution could look like this

```
const int LAYER_BACKGROUNDLAYER = 0;
const int LAYER_FRONTLAYER = 1;
const int LAYER_TOPLAYER = 2;
```

Depending on how many layers you want to use.

Then you simply pass the layer number you want to draw to your Draw-Method. Usually from 0 to the max number.

```
public void DrawLayer(int layer)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < curMap.Layers[layer].Tiles.Count; j++)
    {
        int gid = curMap.Layers[layer].Tiles[j].Gid;

        if (gid == 0)
        { 
            //empty tile
        }
        else
        {
            //draw your tile
        }
    }
}
```

In this case "curMap" is you current .tmx file loaded via *curMap = new TmxMap(mapSource);*
The draw code above should fit to your code since I've based it on the TiledSharp example as well ;)

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful, along with using spritebatch's layer depth. I got it all on screen now.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but I think you need to sort your tiles from back to front. Whichever tiles should be on bottom should be rendered first.

in `for (currentTileLayer=0; currentTileLayer < easyMap.TileLayers.Count; currentTileLayer++)`

replace your TileLayers with `var orderedTiles = easyMap.TileLayers.OrderBy(t => t.Tile.Gid)`

Comment: Unfortunately changing the sorting order doesn't change how it looks, but that's probably a good idea either way. With your second part, TileLayers is actually TmxList<TmxLayer> and it doesn't have the method OrderBy().

Comment: OrderBy is a Linq expression. If you can't use Linq on that object then you can write your own sort method. I'm still somewhat convinced that the error is the order of the rendering. If it's something else I can't think of it.

Comment: It's also possible to make your own `OrderBy()` method as an extension method, if you're brave enough.